# I Have an iPad 4 , I want to move my Minecraft world to my new iPad Pro, I downloaded iExplorer

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I downloaded iExplorer, followed the steps and when I got up to Apps> Minecraft. There weren't any folders in the Minecraft folder. I couldn't see the documents folder or any other one too. can u help me please

Answer (score 0):

Don’t bother with that app
The best way to do it is logging into the same Apple ID on both and backing up Minecraft to iCloud (assuming you have enough iCloud space)

Comment: I dont, Plus my Minecraft world is quite big

Answer (score 0):

Download the app “Addons for Minecraft” from the App Store on both devices then navigate to more > sign in. Upload the world to the app. You should be able to then download it from your new device.

Comment: what add-ons? For Minecraft

Comment: The app is called ”addons for Minecraft".

Comment: If you could please respond so I can help you I would appreciate it.